# Range.Formula with equal sign resulted to Run-Time Error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

The line of code is like this:

```
Range("P46").Formula = "=IF('U:\folder1\folder\" & _
ComboBox1.Text & "\[" & frmadı & "L.xlsx" & "]NAkım'!C4<0;0;1)"
```

It is basic if function, first part is a location with few variables and then the logic test. It is simple but it gives me `Run-Time Error 1004`

I know there is something wrong with the equal sign because when I remove it, the formula works, like this:

```
Range("P46").Formula = "IF('U:\folder1\folder\" & _
ComboBox1.Text & "\[" & frmadı & "L.xlsx" & "]NAkım'!C4<0;0;1)"
```

but of course the calculation is not working.
I also tried this one:

```
Range("P46").Formula = Chr(61) & "IF('U:\folder1\folder\" & _
ComboBox1.Text & "\[" & frmadı & "L.xlsx" & "]NAkım'!C4<0;0;1)"
```

but it is also not working.

Comment: shouldn't the semi-colons in `C4<0;0;1` be commas: `C4<0,0,1`

Comment: The reason it works when you remove the equal sign is because it is not a formula, it is just text.  I recommend you try the formula in a worksheet to verify that it works, then copy the working formula in VBA.  It is difficult to troubleshoot without access to your full code and range names.

Comment: @Darrell H :"copy the working formula in VBA": Will not be helpful if the list separator in the locale will be semicolon. `Range.Formula` needs the formula in en_US format always. That is English function names, comma as list (parameter) separator and dot as decimal separator. This is independent of the locale settings.

Comment: What are the values of ComboBox1.Text  and frmadı ?

Comment: Instead of changing the semicolons to commas, you could try using the `.FormulaLocal` property

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld : "you could try using the .FormulaLocal property ": And so being locale dependent then. This is not an improvement but a deterioration.

Comment: Thanks everyone. But I think this very inpractical and VBA colud even make a error message for this; and it is hard to spot.

Comment: Have you tried what @jamheadart suggested? Second, make sure that you are constructing all bits correctly before you assign it in `.Formula`.